# Match the column heading and print the values of the column using awk

Tags: awk, vmstat

How to print column `free` using `awk` or `sed` command?

Depends on `vmstat` version column, `free` may change from column number 5 to something else.

```
bash-3.00$ vmstat 1 1|tail -2
r b w swap free re mf pi po fr de sr s0 s1 s3 -- in sy cs us sy id
0 0 0 38018936 24998752 122 182 33 81 53 0 0 5 7 -0 0 4113 8416 4527 1 0 99
```

```
bash-3.00$ vmstat 1 1|tail -2|awk '{print $5}'
free
24998752
```

Answer (score 2):

You would, for the first line of input, loop over all fields to find the field that is equal to the string `free`.  You would remember this field number and then use it to output only that field:

```
awk 'NR==1 { for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) if ($i=="free") { n=i; break }} { print $n }'
```

The `NR==1` makes the following block only execute for the very first line, i.e. the header line.  The variable `n` will hold the field number of the `free` field.

Testing it on the `vmstat 1 1|tail -2` data that you present (read from the file called `file` here):

```
$ awk 'NR==1 { for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) if ($i=="free") { n=i; break }} { print $n }' file
free
24998752
```

My original answer used `FNR` rather than `NR`.  Unfortunately, the `awk` on SunOS does not have the `FNR` variable, but in this case the `NR` variable may be use without changing anything else.

Also note that the output of `vmstat` on some systems show the `free` column as `fre` (OpenBSD, for example).  This means that you *may* want to use `$i ~ "^fre"` instead of `$i == "free"`.

Comment: bash-3.00$ vmstat 1 1|tail -2|awk 'FNR==1 { for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) if ($i=="free") { n=i; break }} { print $n }'
 r b w   swap  free  re  mf pi po fr de sr s0 s1 s3 --   in   sy   cs us sy id
 0 0 0 38018928 24998728 122 182 33 81 53 0 0 5 7 -0 0 4113 8416 4527  1  0 99  --> not working

Comment: @RoVo please share the output & full command

Comment: works well in lunix. but not working in SunOS

Comment: @Anavarathan On SunOS, change `FNR==1` to `NR==1`.  With this change, it would still work on Linux.

Comment: working thank you for the great support mate.

Answer (score 1):

Use `csvcut` tool from [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
vmstat 1 1 | tail -2 | tr -s ' ' | csvcut -d ' ' -c free
```

or

```
vmstat 1 1 | tail -2 | csvcut -d ' ' -S -c free
```

Comment: You need to "squeeze" the space to make this work, add `tr -s ' '` after `tail`

Answer (score 0):

I have done by below method

```
for ((i=1;i<=10;i++)); do free -mh| awk -v i="$i" '$i=="free"{x=NR+2}(NR<=x) {print $i}'; done


output
for ((i=1;i<=10;i++)); do free -mh| awk -v i="$i" '$i=="free"{x=NR+2}(NR<=x) {print $i}'; done
free
859M
0B
praveen@praveen:~$
```

Comment: free command not available in sun os

Answer (score -1):

This: vmstat 1 1 | sed -e 's/ +/ /g' | tail -2 | cut -d' ' -f5

Or this: vmstat 1 1 | tail -2 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f5

Comment: This does not solve the problem: `free may change from column number 5 to something else`.

Comment: The issue is that on different systems, the wanted column shifts from being column 5 to being something else.